# aws Cloud search - short query

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

In my cloud search document I have list of persons I want to search in. Now,  let's say there are a people with name `David`, `Dan` and `Dennis`. Everything works alright when I query full name (for example: `David`) - I get back all the persons with the name `David`. But what if I want to return all persons who's name starts with `Da` (so cloud search will leturn `David`, `Dan` and `Dennis`)? Is it possible to achieve this behaviour?

For context: I am building an application where user can search people by name (and some other attributes) and I don't want the user to have to type the full name of person to find...

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found it. I need to use text prefiex:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-text.html#searching-text-prefixes